# how to show info window in google map without click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to show infowindow on page load in google maps. It should automatically show the infowindow pop up. I have multiple markers in the google map. I need all markers info window should open in page load.

js fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/vq7zfbgj/

code:

```
    var locations = [
          [
            "Market 1",
            22.809999,
            86.179999,
            5,
            "Market1",
            "Market1",
            "Market1",
            "found"
        ],
     [
            "Market 2",
            22.801111,
            86.171111,
            5,
            "Market2",
            "Market2",
            "Market2",
            "found"
        ]
    ]

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.803444, 86.179525),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your fiddle to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vq7zfbgj/12/) and the infoWindow will open on page load. I add another marker just to ilustrate that could resolve more markers. Hope it helps.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open multiple markers at once by initiating InfoWindow separately for each marker. I'd suggest removing the original var infowindow and doing the following within the for loop for each marker:

```
marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
});
marker.infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);              
marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vq7zfbgj/16/

Comment: You broke the initial functionality now. While the markers might open on loading they no longer function when clicked anymore and their text is also gone. This is not a solution but introduced more issues.

Comment: @Fran - I didn't carry over the population of the InfoWindow content in my initial example, but I did demonstrate how to open them on page load. It does make sense to retain the click behaviour, so I've reinstated that in my updated example.